# Где скачать установочный exe Android SDK версии не меньше 25?

Tags: android-sdk

Где скачать Android SDK от 25 версии, без установки Android Studio?

Устанавливал 23 версию для React Native , но он просит Android SDK от 25 и больше.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/#command-tools не оно разве? Ну или по прямой ссылке, если нужна конкретная верси https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/studio/#command-tools не оно разве?

Ну или по прямой ссылке, если нужна конкретная верси https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip

Comment: скачал версию 26.0.1. переписал системные переменные.
запускаю а он почему то просит лицензию от 23 версии.

Comment: поправил версию sdk в файле android\app\build.gradle